# Проблемы с ContentProvider ActiveAndroid api-26

Tags: android, android-manifest

Всем хорошего времени суток. Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Намного раньше меня программисты добавили в проект модуль. И теперь папки проекта выглядят как-то вот так
 :[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Добавлено]
Модуль aa- это измененный давно до меня ActiveAndroid. В нем имеется ContentProvider, который и необходимо зарегистрировать в манифесте из-за требований api-26. Попытки зарегистрировать его в главном манифесте приводят к странным и неожиданным проблемам с приложением, которых, по всей логике, не должно быть. Начинают "сыпаться" базы. Выпадают исключения: "нет такой колонки в таблице такой-то", хотя до регистрации все работало нормально.
[Добавлено]
Проблема не новая, вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45925380/securityexception-failed-to-find-provider-null-for-user-0-on-activeandroid-on), например, возникла подобная проблема и, кстати, принятого ответа нет. Если я начинаю регистрировать ContentProvider вот так:

```
<application
        android:name=".VDApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <provider
            android:name="com.activeandroid.sebbia.content.ContentProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
        </provider>
```

то получаю лавину подобных исключений

```
2018-11-02 11:27:21.479 3940-4455/com E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting cached=false responseReason=null source_title=Ведомости last_updated=0 last_modified=null payRequiredExpire=null published_at=2018-11-01T08:55:57.556+03:00 boxes=null was_read=false url=.ru/business/news/2018/11/01/785366-ssha-obognali-rossiyu-po-neftedobiche links=null subtitle=null responseStatus=null categories=null title=США обогнали Россию и вышли на первое место по нефтедобыче в августе docType=NEWS payRequired=null documentId=140737489017238 newspaperTitle=null source_url=http://www.t.ru/
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table news has no column named boxes (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO news(cached,responseReason,source_title,last_updated,last_modified,payRequiredExpire,published_at,boxes,was_read,url,links,subtitle,responseStatus,categories,title,docType,payRequired,documentId,newspaperTitle,source_url) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1472)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1343)
        at com.activeandroid.sebbia.Model.save(Model.java:86)
        at com.model.documents.Document.createDocumentFromJSON(Document.java:246)
        at com.model.documents.Document.create(Document.java:159)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedMethod.call1(AnnotatedMethod.java:125)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createUsingDelegate(StdValueInstantiator.java:248)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1060)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:264)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:124)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3038)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1652)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.treeToValue(ObjectMapper.java:1996)
        at comutils.JSONUtils.parseObject(JSONUtils.java:28)
        at com.model.Reference.create(Reference.java:36)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedMethod.call1(AnnotatedMethod.java:125)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createUsingDelegate(StdValueInstantiator.java:248)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1060)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:264)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:124)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:232)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:206)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:25)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:538)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:106)
2018-11-02 11:27:21.479 3940-4455/com E/SQLiteDatabase:     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:238)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:118)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:538)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:106)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:205)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bind(ObjectReader.java:1234)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:676)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:694)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.treeToValue(ObjectReader.java:1185)
        at com.model.documents.Document.createDocumentFromJSON(Document.java:242)
        at com.model.documents.Document.create(Document.java:159)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedMethod.call1(AnnotatedMethod.java:125)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createUsingDelegate(StdValueInstantiator.java:248)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1060)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:264)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:124)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:232)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:206)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:25)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:538)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:106)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:205)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bind(ObjectReader.java:1234)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:676)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:694)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.treeToValue(ObjectReader.java:1185)
        at com model.NewsDocumentsList.parseAndSave(NewsDocumentsList.java:127)
        at com.model.NewsDocumentsList.processPagingResponse(NewsDocumentsList.java:165)
        at com.model.NewsDocumentsList.performPaging(NewsDocumentsList.java:107)
        at com.model.NewsDocumentsList.performUpdate(NewsDocumentsList.java:82)
        at com.model.UpdatableModel$1.doWork(UpdatableModel.java:160)
        at com.model.UpdatableModel$1.doWork(UpdatableModel.java:156)
        at needle.UiRelatedTask.run(UiRelatedTask.java:20)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
2018-11-02 11:27:21.483 3940-4455/com E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: boxes
2018-11-02 11:27:21.486 3940-4455/com E/sti: Failed to parse JSON while updating NewsDocumentsList
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Instantiation of [simple type, class com.model.documents.Document] value failed: no such column: boxes (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE news SET cached=?,responseReason=?,source_title=?,last_updated=?,last_modified=?,payRequiredExpire=?,published_at=?,boxes=?,was_read=?,url=?,links=?,subtitle=?,responseStatus=?,categories=?,title=?,docType=?,payRequired=?,documentId=?,newspaperTitle=?,source_url=? WHERE Id=-1 (through reference chain: com.model.NewsDocumentsList["fast_news"]->java.util.ArrayList[1])
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.wrapException(StdValueInstantiator.java:405)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createUsingDelegate(StdValueInstantiator.java:266)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1060)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:264)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:124)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:232)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:206)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:25)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:538)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:106)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:205)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bind(ObjectReader.java:1234)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:676)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:694)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.treeToValue(ObjectReader.java:1185)
        at com.model.NewsDocumentsList.parseAndSave(NewsDocumentsList.java:127)
        at com..model.NewsDocumentsList.processPagingResponse(NewsDocumentsList.java:165)
        at com.model.NewsDocumentsList.performPaging(NewsDocumentsList.java:107)
        at com.model.NewsDocumentsList.performUpdate(NewsDocumentsList.java:82)
        at com.model.UpdatableModel$1.doWork(UpdatableModel.java:160)
        at com.model.UpdatableModel$1.doWork(UpdatableModel.java:156)
        at needle.UiRelatedTask.run(UiRelatedTask.java:20)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
     Caused by: android.database.sq
```

Если же убрать provide из манифеста - то все хорошо.

Comment: Может это библиотека. Попытайтесь подключить ее в ручную

Comment: в смысле без манифеста? а папка `manifests`?

Comment: @iFr0z папка manifest находится в app, а нужен манифест конкретно для модуля aa

Comment: На один уровень с res добавьте в app манифест, там ему место. File -> New -> Other в студии.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja я пытался такую вещь сделать, однако она в AndroidStudio не распознается как Manifest

Comment: Это java-модуль - для какой цели Вы решили добавить в него манифест?

Comment: @woesss там имеется content provider. Я его пытался зарегистрировать в главном манифесте, но приложение начало вести себя неадекватно. Модуль aa-это ActiveAndroid и с target api 26+ android o  он стел причиной крашей

Comment: Манифест не поможет - в готовом приложении один манифест и записи всех остальных сливаются в него. Нужно разбираться с самой библиотекой - опишите подробнее проблему и добавьте логи ошибок.

Comment: По отсутствию колонки - Андроид требует, чтобы в таблице обязательно былы колонка с именем `_id` и по ней он индентифицирует строки таблиц. Скорее всего причина в этом.

Comment: @woesss хорошо, сейчас добавлю еще информации, еслиэто поможет

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85223/discussion-between-kostya-m-and-woesss).